# Tratar números python adicionando ponto

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um código simples para converter metros em milímetros. Qual seria a melhor forma para tratar o resultado. Ex: 1000 ou 1.000

Código:

```
valor_m = int(input("Digite um valor em metros: "))
valor_mm = valor_m * 1000

print "Valor em milimetros: %i mm." % valor_mm
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver, preciso só tratar o resultado em valor_mm para ter um ponto a cada três dígitos, contando da direita pra esquerda. Como ficaria isso aplicado ao código acima?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como é possível ver na [documentação](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), para utilizar a formatação com casas de milhares utilizando o caracter `,`, basta o seguinte código:

```
'{0:,}'.format(num_int)
```

Caso você queira modificar a `,` por `.`:

```
'{0:,}'.format(num_int).replace(',','.')
```

Isso só vale para versão do [python](/questions/tagged/python) 2.7+. A partir dessa [resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513747/1606920), é possível fazer para versões mais antigas utilizando o [locale.format()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.format), da seguinte forma:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') #pega o local da máquina e seta o locale
locale.format('%d', num_int, 1)
```

Isso pegará o separador do local. No caso do Brasil, por exemplo, será o `.`, no caso de alguns países, como os EUA, será a `,`. Vale lembrar que é possível alterar o segundo parâmetro para o local desejado.

---

### Exemplo com o código da pergunta

#### Python 2.7+

**Código:**

```
valor_m = int(input("Digite um valor em metros: ")) #se for 2.x deve ser raw_input ao invés de input
valor_mm = valor_m * 1000

resultado = '{0:,}'.format(valor_mm).replace(',','.') #Aqui coloca os pontos
print (resultado)
```

**Input e output:**

```
input:  2345
output: 2.345.000
```

#### Python 2.6-

**Código:**

```
import locale
valor_m = int(raw_input("Digite um valor em metros: "))
valor_mm = valor_m * 1000

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') #pega o local da máquina e seta o locale
resultado = locale.format('%d', valor_mm, 1)
print resultado
```

**Input e output:**

```
input: 2345
output:
   'Portuguese_Brazil.1252' #Caso esteja interpretador no modo interativo
   2.345.000
```

Comment: Meu objetivo é só colocar um . a cada três números, contando da direita pra esquerda. Ainda não consegui utilizando o código acima.

Comment: Vou editar com o seu código para ver se se adequa melhor a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Função recursiva:

```
def milhar(s, sep): # s = string, sep pode ser '.' ou ','
     return s if len(s) <= 3 else milhar(s[:-3], sep) + sep + s[-3:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar as especificações de locale.
Utilize as chaves "grouping" e "thousands_sep" para LC_NUMERIC especificando o separador de milhar.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html

Answer (score -2):

Se percebi bem... é isto que procuram?!

```
valor_m = int(input("Digite um valor em metros: "))
valor_mm = valor_m * 1000

print(f"Valor em milimetros: {valor_mm:,} mm.".replace(',', '.'))

>>> Valor em milimetros: 100.000.000.000.000 mm.
```